# Simple Loop through an array, is using a "for" loop code confusing

Tags: javascript

Loop through an array, is using a "for" loop below ,

```
<html>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var index;

        var text = "<ul>";

        var number = ["one", "two", "three"];

        for (index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
            text += "<li>" + number[index] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text;
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have confusing below step   Kindly please explain this step

```
text =text + "<li>" + number[index] + "</li>";
```

my concern is each time loop executed the variable text(`<ul>`) is added in all the **list item but i know im wrong** any one please help me to explain this step

Comment: It adds each item in the `number` array into the string `text` for each loop iteration, being a list item in the list. My main concern is where `range` is defined, should it be `number.length`?

Comment: Be careful to read about code if you are cutting and pasting it... The for loop has a `range.length` you probably want to change that to `number.length` to get the code to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply appends the newly created `HTML` string to the `text` variable.

```
"<li>" + number[index] + "</li>";
```

will create an `li` tag with the `innerText` of the element at the `index` index from `number` array.

Inside `for` the variable `index` is incremented after each step. So, `number[index]` will be always the unique element from `array`.

At the end of `for` loop, `text` will be as follow:

```
text = '<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>';
```

And `</ul>` is added after the `for` loop is completed.

**EDIT**

As `range` is `undefined` and you want to loop over `number` array, change the `for` as follow:

```
for (index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
//                      ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The UL tag is not added every time the loop executes because it's outside the loop. The LI tag is added every time because it is inside the loop.